# Does message passing using sockets allow to communicate a large amount of data

Tags: sockets

Consider two processes A and B spawned by an application. 
And they want to communicate large chunks of data with each other. 
Can this be done using message passing as in sockets? 
Mainly is the large amount of data feasible or a good way to transfer 
through sockets between processes.

Comment: yes, definitely

Comment: There are more ways to pass data  1. Files 2. Pipes Are those also possible ways ? Or they could cause any problems? Any pros and cons among the 3 ?